# Создание виртуального окружения Python в VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Хотел установить виртуальное окружение для Python но как я знаю должна создаться папка venv при помощи команды python -m venv venv и впоследствии нужно запустить скрипт но папка попросту не создается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал папку на диске C и обозвал ее WEB в ней создал еще одну директорию web_main и уже в ней пытаюсь создать директорию но ничего не происходит кроме надписи Python после выполнения команды.

Comment: Попробуй "py -m venv venv" , должно сработать

Comment: И правда сработало спасибо большое